# Attempting to import from a XPath, seems to always yield blank information

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Currently in my google doc, i'm working on a database for my card worth, and it seems like it doesn't want to grab the information no matter what xpath i want to attempt.

Website i'm trying to take information available [here](https://mavin.io/search?q=Lugia%20NM%209%2F111%20-PSA&bt=sold#). *This is the hyperlink i'm feeding

In the top right corner i'm attempting to grab the worth box information, here is current xpaths i've attempted

```
"//a[@id='worthBox']/h4"
"/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div/a/h4"
"/h4"
"/h4[0-20]"
"//a[@id='worthBox'][1]/h4"
"//div[@id='estimate-box']/a/h4"
"//div[@id='estimate-box']/a[1]/h4"
```

Can someone explain to me why it doesn't seem to wanna fetch, is it even possible?

Thank you so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the URL, the value is put using the Javascript. But `IMPORTXML` cannot retrieve the result after Javascript was run. `IMPORTXML` retrieves the HTML without running Javascript. I think that your xpath is the result after Javascript was run. By this, they cannot be used. But it seems that the value you expect can be retrieved other xpath.

#### Modified xpath:

```
//input[@id='medianHiddenField']/@value
```

#### Sample formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//input[@id='medianHiddenField']/@value")
```

- In this case, the URL of `https://mavin.io/search?q=Lugia%20NM%209%2F111%20-PSA&bt=sold#` put in the cell "A1".

#### Result:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

Comment: @Rafa Guillermo Thank you for your always support!

Comment: @Tanaike  Sorry about the lateness on accepting the answer! I could not find that button for the life of me hahaha, however it seems with your help Tanaike, i'm now running into too many importxml functions, is there any custom functions out there that works quicker than the basic one provided with google sheets? (There is no way for me to limit the amount of calls), that works on the same xpath material?

Comment: @Woahthere Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.

Comment: For sure! one moment :)